# Is there any pdf analyser / debugger to debug a pdf file?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

Is there any validator or PDF analyser which can tell me what is wrong with a PDF I created with a hint or indicator which object in my PDF is wrong or something like that?

I would like to create and understand the PDF file format better and I think I should be pretty close to a working PDF but I can not find the problem in it and why PDF readers are not able to read it.

Isn't there a program or an online service which can give me at least a hint what is wrong with my pdf structure or where the problem occurs or even tell me what is wrong? How to debug something like that?

Here is a link to the PDF (just the attached image converted to a PDF):
https://nonepatchwork.patchwork3d.de/create_pdf/created_pdf.pdf

[image: an png image]

Best regards and thank you very much in advance

Fuchur

Comment: In particular your page object 5 points to object 6 as content stream, but object 6 is not a content stream but an image xobject! (You probably meant to point at object 7.) Furthermore, all your cross reference table offsets are wrong and the **Size** entry in the trailer is wrong. Then there is an `/ID` between **trailer** dictionary and **startxref**. And there probably are more issues, but start by fixing these. Other than that, for software recommendations you should ask on [softwarerecs.se] instead.

Comment: Thank you very much :). I think that got me further but it is not yet right.
I uploaded a new version which hopefully fixed the mentioned issues. Any further clue?
<https://nonepatchwork.patchwork3d.de/create_pdf/created_pdf_2.pdf>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>The request for a *validator or PDF analyser* is not on topic on stack overflow, it's better suited for the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site. In this answer, therefore, I'll focus on analyzing the provided example files.</sub>

#### [created_pdf.pdf](https://nonepatchwork.patchwork3d.de/create_pdf/created_pdf.pdf)

Here a number of issue immediately leap to the eye, in particular:

- Your page object 5 points to object 6 as content stream, but object 6 is not a content stream but an image xobject! (You probably meant to point at object 7.)
- All your cross reference table offsets are wrong.
- The **Size** entry in the trailer is wrong.
- There is an `/ID` between **trailer** dictionary and **startxref**.

There probably are more issues, but start by fixing these.

#### [created_pdf_2.pdf](https://nonepatchwork.patchwork3d.de/create_pdf/created_pdf_2.pdf)

Here you fixed the errors listed above but the file still does not display as expected, Adobe Acrobat Reader in particular says:

[image: Insufficient data for an image.]

Looking at the image dictionary the cause becomes clear:

```cos
6 0 obj << 
        /Type /XObject 
        /Subtype /Image
        /Width 595.276
        /Height 841.89
        /ColorSpace /DeviceRGB 
        /BitsPerComponent 8 
        /Filter/DCTDecode
        /Interpolate true
        /Length 707
    >>  
    ...
```

The values of **Width** and **Height** are floats which is invalid. Furthermore, inspecting the actual image data in the stream it becomes clear that the values are completely incorrect, the image only is 20×20 in size.

Thus, replace the **Width** and **Height** entries by

```cos
        /Width 20
        /Height 20
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes I thought the Image XObject needs to have 1/72-unit too as the page size does and should be the aimed size, but actually there just has to be the pixel size of the image at that place (which is pretty logical if I think about it). Thank you very much for the information :).

Now I got it working with you help and I will accept it as the answer for my problem here. For the question about a PDF validator / analyser I'll see the other link you recommended :).

Many thanks again for your help!